# Mantener ancho de un div con grid

Tags: css, css3

Tengo un **template** creado con `grid`, uno de los **item** de ese `grid` tiene establecido el ancho, pero cuando se muestra, ese **item** se expande de igual manera.

¿Como puedo mantenerlo con el ancho fijo?

Mi código es el siguiente:

```css
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas:
        'img title'
        'img desc'
        'img date';
    width: 100%;
    grid-gap: 0px 10px;
}
.itemImg {
    width: 80px;
    height: 60px;
    grid-area: img;
    background-color: red;
}
.itemTitle {
    width: 100%;
    grid-area: title;
    background-color: green;
}
.itemDesc {
    width: 100%;
    grid-area: desc;
    background-color: blue;
}
.itemDate {
    width: 100%;
    grid-area: date;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="itemImg">Imagen</div>
    <div class="itemTitle">Título</div>
    <div class="itemDesc">Descripción</div>
    <div class="itemDate">Fecha</div>
</div>
```

Como podéis ver, el `.itemImg` es el que tiene establecido un `width` fijo, pero aun así, se expande más.

Comment: No se entiende muy bien lo que quieres conseguir. ¿Podrías subir una imagen en la que se vea la colocación de las columnas que esperas? Ahora mismo, tal y como lo tienes, le estás diciendo al `grid` que quieres 3 filas de dos columnas en las que la primera columna de cada fila esté ocupada por una imagen y que la segunda columna de cada fila esté ocupada en la fila uno por el título, en la dos por la descripción y en la 3 por la fecha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que he entendido lo que quieres hacer. Lo único que te faltaría es especificar lo que quieres que ocupe cada una de las columnas. Lo que he entendido es que quieres que la imagen ocupe 80 píxeles de `width` y que el resto de la fila se ocupe por el contenido de la segunda columna.

Para ello puedes usar la propiedad `grid-template-columns` para especificarlo, ya que por defecto lo que te está sucediendo es que las columnas de cada fila se ven forzadas a ocupar lo mismo.

```css
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas:
        'img title'
        'img desc'
        'img date';
    width: 100%;
    grid-gap: 0px 10px;
    grid-template-columns: 80px 1fr;
}
.itemImg {
    grid-area: img;
    background-color: red;
}
.itemTitle {
    grid-area: title;
    background-color: green;
}
.itemDesc {
    grid-area: desc;
    background-color: blue;
}
.itemDate {
    grid-area: date;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="itemImg">Imagen</div>
    <div class="itemTitle">Título</div>
    <div class="itemDesc">Descripción</div>
    <div class="itemDate">Fecha</div>
</div>
```

Con eso ya no te haría falta especificar la longitud de cada elemento, ya que `grid-template-columns` se ocupa de sus tamaños.

Comment: Perfecto! muchas gracias @phpMyGuel, es justo lo que necesitaba.